# Having Issue with MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In below procedure I have two parameters - when I run should fill both parameters.
I want these parameters optional if i fill first data should be filtered on base of one parameter if i fill the secand one and leave null the first one data should be filtered on base of secand parameter if i passed both parameters it should be filter based on both parameters if i didn't pass a parameter it should not be filtered.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS medatabase.SP_rptProvince2;
CREATE PROCEDURE medatabase.`SP_rptProvince2`(
IN e_Region VARCHAR(500),
IN e_Province VARCHAR(500)
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE strQuery VARCHAR(1024);
  DECLARE stmtp   VARCHAR(1024);


    SET @strQuery = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM alldata where 1=1 ');
   -- IF e_region IS NOT NULL THEN


    -- SET @strQuery = CONCAT(@strQuery, 'AND regionName'=e_Region);
   -- END IF;

    IF e_Region IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @strQuery = CONCAT(@strQuery, ' AND regionName = "',e_Region,'"');


    IF e_Province IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @strQuery = CONCAT(@strQuery, ' AND provinceName = "',e_Province,'"');

   END IF;
   END IF;

  PREPARE  stmtp FROM  @strQuery;
  EXECUTE  stmtp;
 End;
```

Comment: i runt the a above procedure but if have to pass two parameters then it is working if i leave one parameter no data return.

Comment: By the way, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Given that you're using prepared statements, you really ought to consider passing your variables to `EXECUTE` as parameters instead of concatenating them into the SQL; failing that, at very least escape them with [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_quote)!

Comment: Also, I think your first (uncommented) `END IF;` is in the wrong place: shouldn't it appear before the second `IF`?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL procedures do not support optional parameters.  You have to do what you're currently doing (passing in and testing for `NULL`).

Comment: `CALL SP_rptProvince2("region", NULL);`

Comment: i did the same but give me no result and no error there is no result.

Comment: thanks alot sir now it is working i m using toad 6.0 so i used CALL SP_rptProvince2('region', NULL); instaed of double qout i used single qout and it is working. thanks alot

Comment: sir can i assign a default null value to the parameters in procedure?

Comment: @amingul:  No, MySQL procedures do not support optional parameters.  But I'm glad to hear you got the procedure working.  If this answer was helpful, you should [upvote it](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and if it solved your problem, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Thanks!

Comment: @amingul: You need to click the outlined green arrow to the left of the question so that it becomes solid.  If you also think my answer was helpful, you might consider upvoting (clicking the grey arrow above the big "0" so that it becomes orange).